# Accessing Armadillo library using file path c++ Linux OS

Tags: c++, c, linux, linear-algebra, armadillo

Am working a c++ project that uses the armadillo library to compute some linear algebra equations.
To do this, i have downloaded armadillo package and installed successfully and my code/project works good.But now, i want to remove the the installed library(armadillo) and i want to access from a folder that contains the full package of armadillo using a file path.

...is it possible to do so, please.(accessing using file path). if i am in a right way, can i have a simple illustration .

thank u for your time to help me.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have Linux or Mac OS X and a recent version of armadillo unpacked in `/home/kahsay/`, you can use the following command:

```
g++ myprog.cpp -o myprog -O2 -I /home/kahsay/armadillo-4.400.2/include -DARMA_USE_LAPACK -DARMA_USE_BLAS -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER -llapack -lblas
```

Under Mac OS X you may need to use `-framework Accelerate` instead of `-llapack -lblas`

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the compiler where it should look for the Armadillo headers like `g++ -I~/project/embedded_armadillo_headers ...`. To use Armadillo it suffices to provide the header files, you do not need to link against an Armadillo library itself, just make sure to link against BLAS and LAPACK.

Comment: thank u for your response but can you show me one example to include BLAS or LAPACK library to header file

Comment: please help me I get such error Func1.h fatal error: ../libs/armadillo/armadillo: No such file or directory